# serialize string for sending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such code

```
var serializeValues =$(this).find("input[type='hidden']).not('.table-element').serialize();
```

The Value:

```
martial_status=%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82+(%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BC)&evidence_series=11-%D0%B2%D1%84%D1%8B&
```

This string I am sending as data in ajax. But I have table. I am changing my values from table and in the result I have:

```
work_status=working
```

How can I add this string for previous and convert in same format?

**UPD**

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: serializeValues,
        url: url,
        complete: function()
        {
           alert('ok');
        }
    });
```

I want to send this ajax request, serializeValues is a data for this request, after that I use `unserialize` in php to get values.I am getting `serializeValues` automatical from form with the help of `.serialize`. And I am generating some string like `work_status=working` and I want add this string to serialize value, but I can't do it. `data: serializeValues+mystring,` is bad way, because in php `unserialize` doesn't work.

Comment: Not clear..what you want to say..please clear your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I add this string for previous and convert in same format?

Include `&` at beginning of string, use `encodeURIComponent()`, concatenate to `serializeValues`

```
serializeValues = serizlizeValues + encodeURIComponent("&work_status=working")
```